# FAB anchored to app bar doesn't hide on scrolling up

Tags: android, floating-action-button, android-appbarlayout

I have anchored FAB to AppBarLayout. However, on scrolling up the expected behaviour of the FAB is to hide when the toolbar collapses. This does not happen.

Does this have to be handled specially?

The layout I have defined is as below:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/rootLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="256dp"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="206dip"
        android:background="@color/my_primary"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="20dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="16dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <!--<ImageView-->
        <!--android:id="@+id/backdrop"-->
        <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
        <!--android:layout_height="match_parent"-->
        <!--android:fitsSystemWindows="true"-->
        <!--android:scaleType="centerCrop"-->
        <!--app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />-->

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        app:tabMode="scrollable" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_stop_white_24dp"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/appbar"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end" />
```

Comment: Have you tried to add scroll flags ?

Comment: Scroll flags have already been added. Please refer to the layout posted

Comment: I meant scroll flags to the fab

Comment: @MufaddalGulshan it works. I tried it with reyclerview and no viewpager. tried it with cheese sqaure

Comment: @NikolaDespotoski Scroll Flags doesnt work..

Comment: @Raghunandan So is it because of the View Pager?

Comment: @MufaddalGulshan no. i tested your layout with just reyclerview

Comment: @Raghunandan so what is the resolution

Comment: I don't have time to dig too deep right now, but did you ever solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps set a scroll listener to scrollview and hide the fab on demand.

Answer (score 0):

@MufaddalGulshan, the View Pager is probably the issue. Use either recycler view, or NestedScrollView. I read from [here](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Handling-Scrolls-with-CoordinatorLayout) that only views that support "nested scrolling" will work with this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if its still unsolved. But i'll leave it here hope it can help someone. I experienced this issue also and solved by implementing AppBarStateChangeListener then programmatically hide/show the floating action button.

Here's the full implementation:

```
public abstract class AppBarStateChangeListener implements AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener {

public enum State {
    EXPANDED,
    COLLAPSED,
    IDLE
}

private State mCurrentState = State.IDLE;

@Override
public final void onOffsetChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, int i) {
    if (i == 0) {
        if (mCurrentState != State.EXPANDED) {
            onStateChanged(appBarLayout, State.EXPANDED);
        }
        mCurrentState = State.EXPANDED;
    } else if (Math.abs(i) >= appBarLayout.getTotalScrollRange()) {
        if (mCurrentState != State.COLLAPSED) {
            onStateChanged(appBarLayout, State.COLLAPSED);
        }
        mCurrentState = State.COLLAPSED;
    } else {
        if (mCurrentState != State.IDLE) {
            onStateChanged(appBarLayout, State.IDLE);
        }
        mCurrentState = State.IDLE;
    }
}

public abstract void onStateChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, State state);
}
```

Then apply it:

```
appBarLayout.addOnOffsetChangedListener(new AppBarStateChangeListener() {
@Override
public void onStateChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, State state) {
    if(state == State.COLLAPSED){
                fab.hide();
            }else if(state == State.EXPANDED){
                fab.show();
            }   
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:context=".ScrollingActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/app_bar"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:toolbarId="@+id/toolbar"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
                app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_scrolling"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
            app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end"
            app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: If possible, please provide details on your solution.